# Can we use python code in java-cucumber project

Tags: python, java

I have to convert huge delimited file into xlsx file. Python makes this task easy. So can I write one python script for this conversion in my cucumber-java framework.
This python code will just convert file to xlsx then this file will be use for rest of cucumber-java framework.
If this is correct approach, please specify how to achieve this?

Comment: You probably "can" but it doesn't scale well.  The method described below uses files on the file system, this could result in files over-writing each other if you try to convert two files at the same time.  It also uses the hard drive and will be relatively slow.  XLSX appears to be just a zipped XML file, Java can do both of those pretty easily.  There's also Apache Poi, a library for reading and writing MS file formats written in Java.

Comment: P.S. Here's the docs page I found for XLSX file format specifically. https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: You can run (execute) any process from a Java application using the [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class. I included a hyperlink so you can get familiarized with this API. The general form for running a process in Java is as follows:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
```

Inside the `exec` method, you need to provide the details for the executable process you need to run. Another way to spawn a `Process` is by using the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class. To me, this is a much clearer approach:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command(...);
processBuilder.start(); // don't forget to start the process
```

A command can be represented in a single String, or a comma-separated list of arguments. For example:

```
processBuilder.command("hello.exe", "/c", "dir C:/Users/hector");
```

or

```
processBuilder.command("c:/Users/hector/hello.bat");
```

For you, this could look something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("c:/Users/user13987365/convertAndSaveXLSX.py");
processBuilder.start(); // don't forget to start the process
```

Once you save your XLSX, your Cucumber scenario should be able to go to that file location and use the XLSX file for whichever purpose.  OF COURSE, in order to be able to run Python scripts, you need to have it installed and to invoke the python command from any directory, you need to have Python in your path.